# validation is not working inside bootstrap modal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, modal-dialog

I have a problem while validating 2 dates inside a **modal window**.My Model looks like:

```
validate  :check_end_date

  def check_end_date
      if salary_from.present? and salary_to.present?
      if salary_from > salary_to
        errors.add(:salary_to,"ToDate cannot be less than FromDate")
      end
    end
  end
```

It is not showing any error message while i am creating a wrong salary range.Can anyone give a suggestion please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: are you checking presence of salary_from and salary_to by salary_from.present?

Comment: Try with `&&` instead of `and`.Though they both same.Just try it once

Comment: ya.this same code is working fine in other pages but my problem is it is not working in a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
validate  :check_end_date

def check_end_date
  unless salary_from.nil? and salary_to.nil?
    if salary_from > salary_to
     errors.add(:salary_to,"ToDate cannot be less than FromDate")
    end
  end
end
```